# mule rest call response flows execution

Tags: mule

My flow is: from URL invoke the mule url, it invokes the REST call with json data. In mule flow, After rest call, flow invokes Java component with selecting data from db. Now, the issue is, if any error in Java component, error prints in console, but response from rest always goes back with status 200 ie OK. What I need is, after rest call response should be sent back, it should send exception details or the response from the java component ie. response from a component after Rest call and status should not be 200/OK, it should send failed.

```
<flow name="exportjournalentriesFlow1" doc:name="exportjournalentriesFlow1" >
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${port}" path="QBJournalExport/QBGLRest" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component class="com.mycompany.mulesoft.quickbooks.utils.RestService"/>
    </jersey:resources>        
    <set-session-variable variableName="restData" value="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>      
    <db:select config-ref="hrdev" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select company_name, access_token, access_token_secret from dim_access]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
    <set-session-variable variableName="accessToken" value="#[payload.get(0).get('ACCESS_TOKEN')]" doc:name="Access token Session Variable"/>
    <custom-transformer name="StringToNameString" class="com.mycompany.mulesoft.quickbooks.utils.GLExportTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>        
    <set-payload value="#[quickbookspoc.CreateJournalEntry.createJournalEntry(payload,sessionVars['accessToken'],sessionVars['accessTokenSecret'])]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>        
</flow>
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is most probably possible but, to me, this looks like a design issue: you should either do all your actions inside the REST component, potentially calling another flow to do the DB ops (and then you would have regular JAX-RS error handling) or use a regular component in the flow because I suspect `RestService` only has one method (and then you would have regular flow error handling).

Comment: Are you making a REST client (accessing third-party REST server), REST server (providing REST capabilities to your application) or both (design alike a REST proxy)? If you are going to have REST server or proxy, can you utilize APIKit?

Comment: @DavidDossot, you are correct, but it is like completely handling project in Java instead of mule. Get the input values in rest, then get the db details inside rest and handle business functionality inside the java code which makes more of Java code than mule flows.I have found a solution below with response builder.

Comment: @ZlatinZlatev, I haven't used APIKit, I hope this is a wrapper class for Rest api's. Is my problem will be solved by using APIKit? I am creating a rest server response/producing it.

Comment: @akb I was not suggesting to do in Java what you're doing with Mule flow but instead to move the elements that are after the Jersey resources into another flow and call it from within your resource.

Comment: @DavidDossot How that will help to solve the problem?. Request is coming from Ajax call to get details with rest services from UI, get some details from db and insert data into quickbooks with Java component.

Comment: @akb It would help because typically `jersey:resources` should be the only component in the flow. Anything you put after it in the flow potentially messes the responses that Jersey has generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I have found:

```
<custom-transformer name="StringToNameString" class="com.mycompany.mulesoft.quickbooks.utils.GLExportTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>        
<set-payload value="#[quickbookspoc.CreateJournalEntry.createJournalEntry(payload,sessionVars['accessToken'],sessionVars['accessTokenSecret'])]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>        

<choice doc:name="Choice">
       <when expression="#[payload == 'SUCCESS']">
         <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="payload"/>
       </when>
       <otherwise>
         <http:response-builder status="500" contentType="application/json" doc:name="Call Back"/>
       </otherwise>
</choice>
```